# iPhone grouped view borderline without separator line

Tags: iphone, ios

Is that possible that while using grouped view in UItableview and singleline selected and setting the number of the groups to "1", **I want to show the nice rounded border lines** around the whole table but not show the separator lines between rows, **or show some of the separator lines** between rows in the table.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITableView` has an attribute called `separatorStyle`, and one possible value is `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone`, which should do exactly what you want. Another option is to set the `separatorColor` to `[UIColor colorWithwhite:1.0f alpha:0.0f]` (i.e. transparent). Check out the [`UITableView` docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/separatorStyle) at developer.apple.com.

Comment: I want to keep the round borders of the groupud table, seperator style effects all th elines isnt it?